# Making the switch to maps.googleapis.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so there was a blog post a few days back about switching to maps.googleapis.com from maps.google.com you can read about here.

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/10/grab-bag-of-maps-api-news.html

As a consumer  of Google maps API how does it affect me and what changes do I need to make. I know I just import one script file as follows:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

is it as trivial as changing the above one to

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Even when I used maps.google.com my tiles were retrieved from maps.googleapis.com so I am not sure how this change will benefit me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The benefit of moving to maps.googleapis.com is that googleapis.com is a cookieless domain so it is more secure and will be a bit quicker because no cookies are sent.

Also it will avoid a extra redirect if Google decides to 302 maps.google.com to maps.googleapis.com